# Jquery Autocomplete AJAX call for label value pair JSON data

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

This is my Jquery Autocomplete code which is not working for dynamic data. I am having json data as label : contact name and value : contact id but this autocomplete doesnt work for AJAX call.

```
$("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
    //source: data,

    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/leadata.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { q: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el.label,
                        value: el.value
                    };
                });
                alert(transformed);
                response(transformed);
            },
            error: function () {
                response([]);
            }
        });
    },
    response: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length === 0) {
            $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
        } else {
            $("#empty-message").empty();
        }
    },
    focus: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        $("#autocomplete2-value").val(ui.item.value);
        alert(ui.item.value);
        //$('.college').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working", and it would be helpful to see the associated HTML as well.

Comment: <input id="autocomplete2" type="text" placeholder="U.S. state name">
<input id="autocomplete2-value" type="text" name="code"></p>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="../demoengine/demoengine.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../demoengine/demoengine.min.js" defer></script>
<title>jQuery UI Autocomplete: Using Label-Value Pairs</title>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

Comment: I am not able to paste entire code here in comment box. is there other way where I can share html file.

Comment: if I use AJAX for calling data autocomplete with label value is not working.

Comment: You could paste it in your answer, or set up a fiddle at jsfiddle.net, or use a service like pastebin.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote datasource</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
  }
  </style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/autocomplete/test.php",
        minLength: 2,
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $("#empty-message").text("+ Add Contact");
            } else {
                $("#empty-message").empty();
            }
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {                    
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            /*  
            log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            */
            event.preventDefault();
            //$(this).val(ui.item.label);

            $("#birdsval").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#birdsid").val(ui.item.value);
            //$('.college').trigger('click');
            $(this).val('');

        },

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="birds">Birds: </label>
    <input id="birds"><br />
    <input id="birdsid">
    <input id="birdsval">
</div>

<div id="empty-message"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin, how to highlight term text here I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PHP code for test.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("databasename", $conn);

    $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

$return = array();
    $query = mysql_query("select id,firstname from tablename where firstname like '%$q%'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['firstname'],'value'=>$row['id']));
}
echo(json_encode($return));
?>
```